# Print the twelve days of Christmas

Tags: printable-ascii

The goal is simple, print out each day of the twelve days of Christmas, the text should match this exactly

```
On the first day of Christmas my true love gave to me
A partridge in a pear tree

On the second day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the third day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the fourth day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the fifth day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the sixth day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the seventh day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the eighth day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Eight maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the ninth day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Nine ladies dancing
Eight maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the 10th day of Christmas my true love gave to me
10 lords a-leaping
Nine ladies dancing
Eight maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the 11th day of Christmas my true love gave to me
11 pipers piping
10 lords a-leaping
Nine ladies dancing
Eight maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the 12th day of Christmas my true love gave to me
12 drummers drumming
11 pipers piping
10 lords a-leaping
Nine ladies dancing
Eight maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five golden rings
Four calling birds
Three french hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
```